# Split parsed text to seperate date and time android

Tags: java, android, string, split

This code:

```
 else if (tagName.equals(TAG_TIME)) {
      if (item != null) {
           item.mTime_SV = pullParser.getAttributeValue(null, "from");
           System.out.println("time"+ item.mTime_SV);
  }
```

gives me 2014-06-21T08:00:00

Is there a way to split this parsed text 2014-06-21T08:00:00 into two parts, date and time? Am I using the wrong search criteria, am I to simple or is it just not possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `split` to get pieces

Try this

```
  String date = "2014-06-21T08:00:00";
  String[] parts = date.split("T");
  System.out.println("Date: " + parts[0]);
  System.out.println("Time: " + parts[1]);
```

or

```
 String date = "2014-06-21T08:00:00";
 System.out.println("Date: " + date.substring(0, date.indexOf('T')));
 System.out.println("Time: " + date.substring(date.indexOf('T') + 1));
```

**In your case**

```
 else if (tagName.equals(TAG_TIME)) {
      if (item != null) {
           item.mTime_SV = pullParser.getAttributeValue(null, "from");
            String[] parts = item.mTime_SV.split("T");
            System.out.println("Date: " + parts[0]);
            System.out.println("Time: " + parts[1]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
System.out.println("date: " + "2014-06-21T08:00:00".split("T")[0]);
System.out.println("time: " + "2014-06-21T08:00:00".split("T")[1]);
```